# Combine multiple Get-Content cmdlet in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am a beginner to PowerShell and would like to use it to perform an automated file editing. Below is my current work to make a "OR" delimited string:

```
$inputFile = "C:\Users\David Kao\Desktop\Powershell\Input\input.txt"
$outputFile = "C:\Users\David Kao\Desktop\Powershell\Output\output.txt"
$final = "C:\Users\David Kao\Desktop\Powershell\Output\final.txt"
(Get-Content $inputFile ) -replace ' \[.*','' -replace ' \(.*','' -replace ';','' -replace ',','' -replace '- ',''|
    Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '[^\p{IsBasicLatin}]' }|
    Sort-Object -Unique |
    Set-Content $outputFile
    
(Get-Content $outputFile) -join '/' -replace '/','" OR "' -replace '\t" OR ', '' -replace '$', '"'|
    Set-Content $final
```

Here is the sample data:

```
multiple sclerosis [A0484253/AOD/DE/0000006106]
ms [A1145632/BI/AB/BI00548]
multiple sclerosis [A0484254/BI/PT/BI00548]
    
MS [A0432904/CCPSS/PT/0056346]
    
MULTIPLE SCLEROSIS [A0433042/CCPSS/PT/0037395]
    
Multiple sclerosis [A0436411/CCS/MD/6.2.2]
    
Multiple sclerosis [A0436412/CCS/SD/80]
    
Multiple sclerosis [A31482484/CCSR_10/SD/NVS005]
    
disseminated sclerosis [A18685620/CHV/SY/0000008328]
    
insular sclerosis [A18685621/CHV/SY/0000008328]
    
MS [A18592794/CHV/SY/0000008328]
    
MS multiple sclerosis [A18685622/CHV/SY/0000008328]
    
multiple sclerosis [A18611430/CHV/SY/0000008328]
    
multiple sclerosis (MS) [A18555705/CHV/PT/0000008328]
    
multiple sclerosis MS [A18574147/CHV/SY/0000008328]
```

And the output would be something like:

```
"multiple scelorosis" OR "MS" OR "insular sclerosis" OR ....
```

So far as now, this code works well, but what I would like to achieve is to get rid of the second section  and put it into the first section to make it more concise, efficient and professional. Something like this:

```
$inputFile = "C:\Users\helloworld\Desktop\Powershell\Input\input.txt"
$outputFile = "C:\Users\helloworld\Desktop\Powershell\Output\output.txt"

(Get-Content $inputFile ) -replace ' \[.*','' -replace ' \(.*','' -replace ';','' -replace ',','' -replace '- ',''|
    Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '[^\p{IsBasicLatin}]' }|
    Sort-Object -Unique |
    (Get-Content $_) -join '/' -replace '/','" OR "' -replace '\t" OR ', '' -replace '$', '"'|
    Set-Content $outputFile
```

I have googled a lot about this issue but got stuck for a while.
Can anyone help me out?
Thanks!

---

I am now adding `ForEach-Object`:

```
$inputFile = "C:\Users\David Kao\Desktop\Powershell\Input\input.txt"
$outputFile = "C:\Users\David Kao\Desktop\Powershell\Output\output.txt"

(Get-Content $inputFile ) -replace ' \[.*','' -replace ' \(.*','' -replace ';','' -replace ',','' -replace '- ',''|
    Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '[^\p{IsBasicLatin}]' }|
    Sort-Object -Unique |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -join '/' -replace '/','" OR "' -replace '\t" OR ', '' -replace '$', '"'}|
    Set-Content $outputFile
```

But it seems that `join` does not work it `ForEach-Object`, if I can fix this, then I think everything would be fine.

Comment: without some sample data, the following is rather vague ... however, the 2nd code block does not need the 2nd `Get-Content`. instead, pipe to `ForEach-Object` and continue working, OR do the `Sort-Object -Unique` before or after the replacement calls.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks for the advise, however due to the characteristics of the file, it seems like the order needs to be the way I demonstrate, if changes then it won't work out.

Comment: I just tried to pipe to ```ForEach-Object``` but ```-join```doesn't seem to work in ```ForEach-Object```

Comment: kool! [*grin*] the 2nd `Get-Content` in the 2nd code block appears wrong, tho. it is supposed to load `$_` and that otta be a string at that point ... is that string a file name? ///// again, without some realistic sample data, there just aint much that can be said about your code beyond that.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I 've just added sample data, please kindly have a look

Comment: neat! another question ... does the input data REALLY have a line with just 4 spaces between each line of data?

Comment: also, how to handle the 5 variants for `multiple sclerosis` - `ms, MS multiple sclerosis, multiple sclerosis, multiple sclerosis (MS), multiple sclerosis MS`?

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following, which assumes all spaces are a single space and names will only contain alpha characters and spaces.

```
$inputfile = Get-Content inputfile.txt
($inputfile -replace '(^[a-z][a-z ]*) [^a-z].*$','"$1"' -ne '' |
    sort -unique) -join ' OR ' | Set-Content output.txt
```

See [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/jlURcc/1/) for matching explanation. Capture group `1` is everything matched within the first `()` grouping. It is substituted in the replace string as `$1`.

`-ne ''` is to remove solitary blank lines. If there are other spaces on those lines you may need an additional `-notmatch '^\s*$'`.

If you have a custom definition of uniqueness, then the code will need to be altered slightly rather than doing just `sort -unique`.

Answer (score 0):

here's another way to do this ... [*grin*]

what it does ...

- creates a set of sample data to work with
  when ready to work with real data, replace the entire `#region/#endregion` block with a `Get-Content` call.
- splits the lines on the open `[`
- filters out the lines that have a closing ']'
  that gets rid of the unwanted remainder from the split.
- filters out any lines that contain 2-or-more consecutive spaces
  this gets rid of those odd lines that have just 4 spaces on them.
- trims away any leading or trailing spaces
- sorts the items and removes any exact dupes
- joins the items with double-quoted OR strings
- assigns that to `$Result`
- adds the required leading and trailing double quotes to the previous string
- assigns that to `$FinalResult`
- displays that last item on screen

the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a plain text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
multiple sclerosis [A0484253/AOD/DE/0000006106]
ms [A1145632/BI/AB/BI00548]
multiple sclerosis [A0484254/BI/PT/BI00548]

MS [A0432904/CCPSS/PT/0056346]

MULTIPLE SCLEROSIS [A0433042/CCPSS/PT/0037395]

Multiple sclerosis [A0436411/CCS/MD/6.2.2]

Multiple sclerosis [A0436412/CCS/SD/80]

Multiple sclerosis [A31482484/CCSR_10/SD/NVS005]

disseminated sclerosis [A18685620/CHV/SY/0000008328]

insular sclerosis [A18685621/CHV/SY/0000008328]

MS [A18592794/CHV/SY/0000008328]

MS multiple sclerosis [A18685622/CHV/SY/0000008328]

multiple sclerosis [A18611430/CHV/SY/0000008328]

multiple sclerosis (MS) [A18555705/CHV/PT/0000008328]

multiple sclerosis MS [A18574147/CHV/SY/0000008328]
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#endregion >>> fake reading in a plain text file

# split on the open "["
$Result = (($InStuff -split '\[').
    Where({
        # filter out the lines that have a closing "]"
        $_ -notmatch '\]' -and
        # filter out the lines that have two-or-more consecutive spaces
        $_ -notmatch '\s{2,}'
        }).
    # trim away any leading/trailing spaces
    Trim() |
    # sort the items and toss out any dupes.
    # does a preliminary join with double-quoted OR strings
    Sort-Object -Unique) -join '" OR "'

# adds leading and trailing double quotes
$FinalResult = '"{0}"' -f $Result

$FinalResult
```

output ...

```
"disseminated sclerosis" OR "insular sclerosis" OR "ms" OR "MS multiple sclerosis" OR "multiple sclerosis" OR "multiple sclerosis (MS)" OR "multiple sclerosis MS"
```